# Booked with third party - How do I get my flights back?

Tags: air-travel, uk

Basically, I booked a packaged holiday with a third party company, flying with Thomas Cook. I am very disappointed with them.

I have already paid (£400) which covers the flights, so technically, the flights have already been paid for. My question is: If I call Thomas Cook, explain the situation will they allow me to go onto these flights, without having to use the third party? I can find a better, cheaper hotel than they have quoted me. TECHNICALLY, I have already paid for the flights, just not the hotel yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have booked two separate items, a flight reservation and a hotel booking, and paid only the airfare portion of the bill, then perhaps the third party will allow you to keep the air.

If you booked a package deal, airfare plus hotel and have paid 400 towards that package then you are stuck with that package to continue with or cancel in its entirety. Tour companies do not break packages, especially not cheap air / hotel combos.

Contacting Thomas Cook directly won't change the outcome, because the tour operator likely still has your money.

One thing to keep in mind with version one, a lot of tour companies specifically state that the low airfare is only available when booked with a hotel, so cancelling the hotel may cause the airfare to go up.